# How do I stop the format attribute of datepicker controls from changing?

Tags: vb6

I'm working on a legacy VB6 application with many forms.

Visual Basic stores datepicker controls in a form as follows:

```
      Begin MSComCtl2.DTPicker txtStartdatum 
         Height          =   315
         Left            =   11640
         TabIndex        =   68
         Top             =   1320
         Width           =   1455
         _ExtentX        =   2566
         _ExtentY        =   556
         _Version        =   393216
         Format          =   65994753
         CurrentDate     =   40000
      End
```

Every time a form with a datepicker control is saved, the format attribute changes. I have no idea why, and I would like to prevent this as it always causes a merge conflict when merging branches in Git.

Does anyone know what the cause could be?

Comment: Unfortunately this type of thing is very common in VB6.  My team we just know to never commit changes like that unless they were made deliberately.  Does it always change to the SAME value?

Comment: Due to the ANSI nature of the files I'm told to never cherry-pick lines in GitKraken, so those always get committed.

The value it changes to seems to be random.

Comment: I can say from experience in my own code base (yours could differ) cherrypicking like this has never caused us problems.  That said if your practice is not to do that, they I could suggest doing it in 2 commits. One for these unwanted changes with an appropriate description, and a second for the intended / meaningful code change.

Comment: For the cases I've seen this kind of behavior (not necessarily with DatePicker specifically) its often minor changes to control positions, sizes, or font sizes made by VB6. I have the impression that these might be tied to the current user's Windows display settings, something like that.  Why such changes never seem to have any effect on the running application is not clear however, but they don't.